# Best way to form a two column DataFrame where the scond column is a transformation of the first?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to form a two column DataFrame where the first columns consists of a sequence of random variables and the second column a constant multiple of the first plus a random factor.

The following code give me the two desired two columns (plus one extra!) - but feels far from optimal.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# a random sample from $U(0,100)
df = pd.DataFrame(100 * np.random.random(100), columns=['x'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(100), columns=['y'])

df['transformed_x'] = (1.6 * df)
df['y'] = df.bx + df2.y
```

At first I tried something as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(100 * np.random.random(100), columns=['x'])
df['y'] = (1.6 * df5) + pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(100))
```

But that gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

I have two questions that I need help with:

1. How may the problem be solved better than I did?
2. Why does the later code sample generate an error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame(100 * np.random.random(100), columns=['x'])
    df['y'] = df['x']*1.6 + np.random.randint(1, 100, df.shape[0])
```

As to why the first method doesn't work I'm unsure!

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, you can keep `x` and `y` as numpy arrays then combine them to make a dataframe:

```
n = 100
x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, n)
y = 1.6 * x + np.random.random(n)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'y': y
})
```

Comment: is there any particular reason for stating the index when constructing this data frame? It seems as though it's not needed

Comment: Yes, you are right. The index is not needed. I forgot to remove it from earlier code. Removed